# Правильный хэш sha256 в Excel

Tags: excel, vba, sha256

Есть модуль Excel, взят отсюда https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications/String_Hashing_in_VBA:

```
Public Function SHA256h(sIn As String) As String
   Dim oT As Object, oSHA256 As Object
   Dim TextToHash() As Byte, bytes() As Byte
   Set oT = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding")
   Set oSHA256 = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed")
      sIn = Converthex(sIn) 'дополнено'
      TextToHash = oT.GetBytes_4(sIn)
      bytes = oSHA256.ComputeHash_2((TextToHash))
      SHA256h = ConvToHexString(bytes)
   Set oT = Nothing
   Set oSHA256 = Nothing
End Function

Private Function ConvToHexString(vIn As Variant) As Variant
   Dim oD As Object
   Set oD = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
   With oD
    .LoadXML "<root />"
    .DocumentElement.DataType = "bin.Hex"
    .DocumentElement.nodeTypedValue = vIn
   End With
   ConvToHexString = Replace(oD.DocumentElement.Text, vbLf, "")
   Set oD = Nothing
End Function
```

Но результат меня не устраивает. Применяю к строкам в Excel, получаю:
SHA256h(11)=4fc82b26aecb47d2868c4efbe3581732a3e7cbcc6c2efb32062c08170a05eeb8

Я же хочу получить результат:
SHA256h(11)=4a64a107f0cb32536e5bce6c98c393db21cca7f4ea187ba8c4dca8b51d4ea80a

Как адаптировать сей код на другой тип входных данных? Проверяю по http://www.fileformat.info/tool/hash.htm

Единственное что удалось найти это доп.функцию:

```
Private Function Converthex(strHexString As String) As String
    Dim intLenOfString As Integer
    Dim intCounter As Integer
    Dim strBuild As String
    If Len(strHexString) = 0 Or Len(strHexString) Mod 2 <> 0 Then Exit Function
    intLenOfString = Len(strHexString)

    For intCounter = 1 To Len(strHexString)
        If intCounter Mod 2 <> 0 Then
        strBuild = strBuild & Chr$(Val("&H" & Mid$(strHexString, intCounter, 2)))
        Converthex = strBuild
    End If
    Next
End Function
```

Она дает почти нужный результат. Но не для hex-значений с "буквами":
sha256h(FF)=8a8de823d5ed3e12746a62ef169bcf372be0ca44f0a1236abc35df05d96928e1

А должен
sha256h(FF)=a8100ae6aa1940d0b663bb31cd466142ebbdbd5187131b92d93818987832eb89

Ткните носом. Что я делаю не так, и куда копать? (Длина моих сообщений порядка 160 байт)

Comment: `4a64a107f0cb32536e5bce6c98c393db21cca7f4ea187ba8c4dca8b51d4ea80a` - это хеш вообще от чего?

Comment: От такой же величины, в данном примере "11".

Comment: Я воспользовался вашей ссылкой на сайт - у меня для "11" получается хеш -  4fc82b26aecb47d2868c4efbe3581732a3e7cbcc6c2efb32062c08170a05eeb8 А какой должен?

Comment: Второе поле Binary hash. Оно же hex bytes

Comment: Вы ввели 11 в строку для бинарных даных. Тоесть это хеш от массива [0x11]. Ваша функция в примере считает хеш от массива байт полученого из строки, тоесть для 11 это будет [0x31, 0x31]

Comment: Верно. А не подскажите ли как мне string на входе преобразовать в binary hex? Новую функцию? Или все же не смогу скормить бинарные данные "System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed" ?

Comment: SHA256Managed не умеет работать со строками в hex. Вам придется конвертировать как-то, что бы передать массив байт.

Comment: таким образом от этой реализации придётся отказаться..

Comment: Я так понимаю класс который описан в https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22672564/porting-sha-256-library-to-excel тоже не сможет съесть hex строку..

Comment: Зачем вы ищите реализации SHA256, вам нужно просто преобразовать хекс-строку в массив байт...